# Partition IDs in database

Tags: sql

I need to partition SQL table records into equal parts of 100 and get their ranges by id. IDs are increasing, but some are missing. So every part should have 100 records.

Like

```
0 part :from 5 to 120
1 part :from 121 280
...
```

Is it possible to make it in pure SQL? It looks very complex to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       floor( (seqnum - 1) / 100) as part_num
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```